# Remove characters in img tag with jquery or regex

Tags: jquery, regex, string, character

I would like to remove certain characters in my img tag that is a list item in a loop. 
I would like to get rid of:  `" li="" ..."` but keep my image src intact. Any help would be awesome!!

```
 This is my output:

   <li>
   <img li="" ...<="" src="myimage.jpg?932">
   <li>
```

This is what Ive tried but no luck...

```
$("#blogs li").each(function(i) {
   $(this).children('img').find('...<="" li="">').remove().end().html();
});
```

Comment: Why not fix your code on the server?

Comment: Can you post your serverside code that generates the img tag?

Comment: geez, that was quick thanks everyone!!! I am working with in the shopify framework and have a ton of other stuff....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix your loop code, instead of using JavaScript. Try using.  `replaceWith` method.

```
$("#blogs li img").replaceWith(function(){
   return '<img src="'+this.src+'"/>';
})
```

Comment: I think this is the better answer, assuming it works; and assuming the imgs don't need additional attributes

Comment: @ZachL Thanks for saying this. But I think best answer for this question is 'fix your serverside code', Using JavaScript is not a good option for fixing the markup.

Answer (score 3):

Check out: [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

as in:

```
$("#blogs li").each(function(i) {
   $(this).children('img').removeAttr('li');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for .each:

```
$("#blogs li img").removeAttr('li');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like li have no ending tag
I fear that the parser will fail against this :/

Have you tried this

```
$("#blogs li").each(function(i) {
   alert($(this).html()); // or alert($(this).children().html());
});
```

Why not to try fixing on server side?

Comment: $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/img.+src/,'img src'));